# Get value by key in Array Object to Array in mongodb & mongoose by query

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a question about `mongodb`.

I have a collection with documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5445b44ae5aa0c0c625378"),
    "skills" : [ 
        {
            "skillId" : 11,
            "level" : 10,
            "available" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b5445b44ae5aa0c0c62537c")
        }, 
        {
            "skillId" : 12,
            "level" : 10,
            "available" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b5445b44ae5aa0c0c62537b")
        }, 
        {
            "skillId" : 13,
            "level" : 1,
            "available" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b5445b44ae5aa0c0c62537a")
        }, 
        {
            "skillId" : 14,
            "level" : 1,
            "available" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b5445b44ae5aa0c0c625379")
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I want to select all skill -> level  in this document to an array in new object with current id

Ex :

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b5445b44ae5aa0c0c625378"),
"skills": [10, 10,1,1] 
}
```

Result is same as aggregate query `[{$project:{  "skills": "$skills.level" }}]`
but aggregate is not recommended in this case!

Can you tell me how I using find in Mongoose to do that?